# Survival analysis using Kaplan-Meier estimator

Tags: survival

What are the needed codes in matlab for survival analysis using Kaplan-Meier method? Im just a beginner thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this type of question yourself by simply doing a Google search for the keywords: "Matlab" and "survival analysis" or by checking Matlab's comprehensive website. I suspect this is the reason your question was downvoted.

In any event, this link should get you started:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/survival-analysis.html?requestedDomain=true